# How can you incorporate/sync specific table details from Azure database for Postgres into SQL Server?

Tags: azure-database-postgresql

It is for an asp.net core project following microservice architecture.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, sync feature isn't available for your requirement. Though Azure provides Data Sync services, but this only supports Azure SQL database. It is not available for Azure PostgreSQL database.

Comment: Thanks for the reply,but do you know if any 3rd party tool could be utilised to serve this purpose?